# ReadonlyArray in redux/ngrx state?

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, redux, ngrx

I've seen a lot of examples where people create their state types in redux/ngrx like:

```
export interface PartOfSomeState {
  someList: SomeResponse[]
}
```

Wouldn't this be better way of doing this if we have in mind this should be immutable anyway?

```
export interface PartOfSomeState {
  someList: ReadonlyArray<SomeResponse>
}
```

Comment: Sure ... you can read about it here : https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#reducer-state